# C language how to remove element in vector

Tags: c, vector

I have used vector from
[link](http://www.happybearsoftware.com/implementing-a-dynamic-array.html)

which provide method to initial, get, and set vector as the code below.

```
// vector.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "vector.h"

void vector_init(Vector *vector) {
   // initialize size and capacity
    vector->size = 0;
    vector->capacity = VECTOR_INITIAL_CAPACITY;

   // allocate memory for vector->data
   vector->data = malloc(sizeof(int) * vector->capacity);
}

void vector_append(Vector *vector, int value) {
   // make sure there's room to expand into
   vector_double_capacity_if_full(vector);

   // append the value and increment vector->size
   vector->data[vector->size++] = value;
}

int vector_get(Vector *vector, int index) {
   if (index >= vector->size || index < 0) {
       printf("Index %d out of bounds for vector of size %d\n", index,  vector->size);
       exit(1);
   }
   return vector->data[index];
}

void vector_set(Vector *vector, int index, int value) {
  // zero fill the vector up to the desired index
  while (index >= vector->size) {
  vector_append(vector, 0);
}

void vector_double_capacity_if_full(Vector *vector) {
   if (vector->size >= vector->capacity) {
   // double vector->capacity and resize the allocated memory accordingly
   vector->capacity *= 2;
   vector->data = realloc(vector->data, sizeof(int) * vector->capacity);
}
```

From the code above, there have no delete function.
How could I implement or do it if I would like to delete such an element in a vector object.

Comment: Did you just miss `vector_double_capacity_if_full()`?

Comment: oh yes, I really sorry.I have edited it already.

Comment: The C language don't have vectors. You need to implement them yourself. The C++11 language does have `std::vector`

Answer (score 1):

Deleting an element of vector implies moving all subsequent elements one position back.

I give you code to delete the last element, just change it to delete a specific element and move all elements

```
void vector_delete_last(Vector *vector) {
    if (vector->size) {
        vector->size -= 1;
    } // else /* error */;
}
```

or make a `vector_swap()` to exchange two elements and then delete the last one.

Answer (score 0):

A vector, as commonly used in things like [C++'s standard library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) simply doesn't really have great "remove" functionality, because they rely on elements being in memory one directly after the other -- so if you remove one element from the middle, all following elements will need to be relocated. From above link:

> Because vectors use an array as their underlying storage, erasing
>   elements in positions other than the vector end causes the container
>   to relocate all the elements after the segment erased to their new
>   positions. This is generally an inefficient operation compared to the
>   one performed for the same operation by other kinds of sequence
>   containers (such as list or forward_list).

The author of your C implemented vector might just not have implemented such an inefficient operation. You'll have to write a loop (or a memmove) that moves all the elements after the one you've deleted "backwards" in memory by one place. All in all, because of the way you're asking this: you've chosen the wrong container if you often need to delete elements.

Comment: It's not necessarily the wrong container : On many machines `memmove` is not that slow. On the other hand, accessing the nth element of a linked list is always very slow. So if you remove and add in the middle less often than you access random elements, it's still justified to use a vector.